# How can I get a unknown number from a string within a certain part of the string?

Tags: php, regex, string

My string:

```
How would you rate the ease and comfort required to undertake the session?@QUESTION_VALUE_0
```

How would I be able to get this value specifically from the above string? I don't know what this value will be (apart from that it will be an integer):

`(some question)@QUESTION_VALUE_X` where X is an integer, I want to get X.

I looked into Regex, but I suck at regular expressions, so I'm at a loss, cheers guys!

About as far as I got with regex

```
/@QUESTION_VALUE_[0-9]+/
```

But I can't get the number out of the string. How can I only grab the number?

Comment: *I looked into Regex* Show your attempts and where exactly you are stuck

Comment: @Rizier123, I've made an edit to the post above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

Just put the [`escape sequence`](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php) **\d** (which means **0-9**) with the [`quantifier`](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.repetition.php) **+** (which means **1 or more times**) into a **group** (**()**) to capture the the number which you then can access in the array `$m`.

```
<?php

    $str = "How would you rate the ease and comfort required to undertake the session?@QUESTION_VALUE_0";
    preg_match("/@QUESTION_VALUE_(\d+)/", $str, $m);
    echo $m[1];

?>
```

output:

```
0
```

If you do `print_r($m);` you will see the structure of your array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => @QUESTION_VALUE_0
    [1] => 0
)
```

And now you see ^ that you have the full match in the first element and then first group (**(\d+)**) in the second element.